# Fancybox Safari Prev/Next Buttons Cut Off

Tags: jquery, safari, fancybox

I've added the code to make the prev/next buttons show up on the outside of the image instead of inside using jsfiddle instructions:

```
$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    nextEffect  : 'none',
    prevEffect  : 'none',
    padding     : 0,
    margin      : [20, 60, 20, 60] // Increase left/right margin
});

.fancybox-nav {
width: 60px;       
}

.fancybox-nav span {
visibility: visible;
opacity: 0.5;
}

.fancybox-nav:hover span {
opacity: 1;
}

 .fancybox-next {
right: -60px;
 }

 .fancybox-prev {
left: -60px;
 }
```

In Safari the arrows are cut off making it difficult to click on them. The gallery is here:
http://southamptonbuilding.com/relaunch/southampton-building-gallery.shtml

I appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: they look good to me: what version of safari and OS?

Comment: OS 10.8.4 and Safari 6.0.5. Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing. The arrows stay like this even when I resize the screen. http://southamptonbuilding.com/relaunch/safariissue.png 
Thank you!

Comment: maybe if you add a `maxWidth` of `80%` to test and make room for the buttons

Comment: Thank you - sorry for my ignorance, but where would I add the max-width? What part of the CSS?

Comment: add it in your custom script like your other options (`openEffect`, `closeEffect`, etc.) example `$(".fancybox").fancybox({ maxWidth : "80%", ...` check the API documentation http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs